# Save and restore a cmder tabs session?

Tags: windows, conemu

I would like to layout a collection of tabs with each one having a different starting path and i'd like to be able to save this layout and restore it with a single click.

I want this in order to run the same git commands across multiple repos.

Is this possible?

Comment: If it turns out not to be possible with your particular shell, just use a keyboard macro and record the keystrokes needed to do that manually.

Comment: Have you read docs?! http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html

Comment: Thanx @Maximus. How can i also automatically group the input of all consoles i create on startup?

Comment: Execute `ConEmuC -GuiMacro GroupInput` from the last created tab?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is terribly off-topic here. It's not about programming at all, you don't have any code you need to help with, etc.

Comment: Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Dawid it is about "programming". I need a way to run concurrent git commands on multiple repos and cmder is the only tool i have found so far that can do it.

Answer (score 145, accepted):

The simplest way I've found is to arrange the tabs and splits the way you want, and then on "Settings" -> Startup -> Tasks:

1. Create a new task using the "+" (plus sign) at the bottom of the predefined task list.
2. Give the task a name
3. Click "Active tabs"
4. Click "Save settings"

[image]

If you want to make it the default at startup, then:

1. Go to "Settings"->Startup
2. On "Specified named task" select the name of your recently created task.
3. Save the settings.

[image]

That's it! Now when you open the Cmder it will restore your layout with each corresponding path.

Comment: This was SO very helpful! This is an amazing CMDer tip! -- But seriously, when will they add "save tab session"?

Comment: For some reason it doesn't maintain same pane layout. Otherwise a nice find.

Comment: sounded good, but it didn't kept the paths on WSL2... the tab names did survive.

Comment: This doesn't restore the directory I was in for each tab -- anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 52):

You can also do it like this in newer versions

[image].

Comment: Excellent, for some reason I saw this option but didn't recognize the function...

Comment: This is good up to a point. If you try to open up Cmder again as in (right click in folder open Cmder) the task will be run again and you will have duplicated all of your consoles. Not so good IMO.

Answer (score 9):

As @Maximus mentioned i created a new Task (http://conemu.github.io/en/Tasks.html) after I had setup my console layout and clicked Active Tabs. This saved my layout to the new task and after updating my Windows Jump List i can now directly open this exact layout.

Answer (score 1):

This Worked For Me

```
>cmd.exe /k RenameTab "Tab1" & "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & cd /d C:\project

cmd.exe /k RenameTab "Tab2" & "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & cd /d C:\project

cmd.exe /k RenameTab "Tab3" & "%ConEmuBaseDir%\CmdInit.cmd" & cd /d C:\project
```

Comment: This is really helpful. Every line will open a new tab.

Comment: You can also have it for bash:   

* -cur_console:d:"C:\xampp\htdocs" -cur_console:t:Bash-Main -cur_console:C:"D:\Cmder\...\icons\cmder.ico" cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i" 

>* -cur_console:d:"C:\xampp\htdocs\" -cur_console:t:Bash-Server -cur_console:C:"D:\Cmder\...\icons\cmder.ico" cmd /c ""%ConEmuDir%\..\git-for-windows\bin\bash" --login -i"

Answer (score 0):

Very useful tip by PDG. Thank you. 
After making this change, whenever I click on `+` icon it recreates all the tabs.I wanted to open a set of tabs only when I open ConEmu.
To open single tab later:
Go to

`"Settings"->Startup ->Tasks`

Select the task you want to open when `+` icon is clicked (Ex:Shells::PowerShell (Admin)), Flag Checkbox Default task for new console. 
This way when you open ConEmu, the task setup as startup task will open. Clicking `+` icon will open single tab set as default.